# Trouble restarting my grid loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The program currently runs with no errors in dev tools. Everything is performing besides the last part of code. After I enter the input in the prompt the container clears but will not let me draw inside of it with the newly set variables?

```
var row=16;
var sizeofsquare=45;

function gridLife() {
  for (var x = 0; x < row; x++){
    for (var y = 0; y < row; y++){
  $("<div class='square'></div>").appendTo(".container");
}
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  gridLife();
 $('.square').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
      });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.buttons').click(function(){
  $('.container').empty();
  row = prompt ('How many sqaures would you like?');
  sizeofsquare = 720/row;
});
});
```

Comment: You might need to put the focus back on the element you want to draw in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're removing all the squares by calling `$('.container').empty()`, but not putting them back afterwards.  At the end of your button click handler, you should call `gridLife()` again to regenerate the grid elements.

However, it will still not work because only the original square elements had the `mouseenter` events bound.  The new squares won't have that event handler anymore.  You *could* fix this by calling `$('.square').on` again, but that's messy.  The best way is to use the optional selector argument to `.on()`, like this:

```
$('.container').on('mouseenter', '.square', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});
```

Now, all `.square` elements that *ever* exist within the `.container` element will automatically trigger that same event.